# PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$results in analyst.php on line 23

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to take prices in json and then  upload it to mysql table, but i get this error:

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$results in analyst.php on line 23

23rd LINE is:

```
$items_count = count($items->results);
```

s

```
$db = new db(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
if($db) echo "   => Connected!\n";
else exit("   => ERROR! Aborting!\n");

echo "=> Getting new pricelist from analyst\n";
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://analyst.x-se.ru/");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $urljson = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
}
if($urljson) echo "   => Completed!\n";
else exit("   => Failed! Aborting!\n");

$items = (object)json_decode($urljson);
$items_count = count($items->results);
$percent = 0;
echo "   => Downloaded $items_count items\n";
if($items_count < 2000) exit("=> Incorrect array of items, aborting!\n");
```

Comment: what is your 23rd line's code?

Comment: `var_dump($items)` and check result is available or not

Comment: `results` is not present in your `$items`

Answer (score 0):

`$items` object is coming from `$urljson` variable. If `$urljson` is not present, it is obvious it will show **NOTICE** about that variable.
So, according to me, when you are checking in `if($urljson){`, you can place those 2-3 lines of code in this scope only.

`$urljson` is not initialized in else condition.

If `$urljson` is present, your code will progress further. Otherwise, `else` will get executed.

***Updated Code***

```
$db = new db(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
if($db){
  echo "   => Connected!\n";
} else {
  exit("   => ERROR! Aborting!\n");
}

echo "=> Getting new pricelist from analyst\n";
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://analyst.x-se.ru/");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $urljson = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
}

if($urljson){
  echo "   => Completed!\n";

  $items = (object)json_decode($urljson);
  $items_count = count($items->results);
  $percent = 0;
  echo "   => Downloaded $items_count items\n";
  if($items_count < 2000){
    exit("=> Incorrect array of items, aborting!\n");
  }

} else {
  exit("   => Failed! Aborting!\n");
}
```